# Remove all spaces between a character on a line without creating one huge single line

Tags: perl, replace

I am currently facing a problem that seems easy to deal with but I haven't been able to solve it so far. I have a "pipe separated value" file and I would like to remove all leading and trailing spaces on all values on every line. This file may contain several lines.

Example:

```
1|     | Field2     | Field3
2| 123 | Field2     |
3|     |            | Field3
```

What I want after removing the spaces:

```
1||Field2|Field3
2|123|Field2|
3|||Field3
```

What I have so far works as long as the last field (in this case Field3) is not NULL. This correspond to line 2 on the example above. When the last field is NULL it concatenates that line with the next one creating a bigger line than what is expected.

My code so far is this one:

```
$res =~ s/\s*\|\s*/\|/g;
```

As mentioned previously this works as long as the last field on all lines is not NULL. I have tried to come up with a regex that matches all occurrences of a pipe except the last one but without success so far.

Any idea how I could remove all spaces and maintain the line integrity?

Thanks in advance,

João

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex `/\s/` matches carriage-returns and newlines (amongst other things) as well as spaces and tabs, so your substitution will delete the trailing newline on records with null final fields.

Try

```
$res =~ s/[ \t]*\|[ \t]*/|/g;
```

or

```
$res =~ s/[ ]*\|[ ]*/|/g;
```

if you're not interested in removing tab characters.

(The pipe in the replacement string doesn't need escaping.)

Comment: Hi Borodin, thanks for your answer. It was exactly what I wanted. Thanks everyone for all your answers. I have no idea why they have a negative value...

Answer (score 0):

```
my $file_data = <<DATA;
1|     | Field2     | Field3
2| 123 | Field2     |
3|     |            | Field3
DATA

foreach my $line (split /[\n\r]/, $file_data) {
    my @fields;

    foreach my $field (split /\|/, $line) {
            $field =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/;
            push @fields, $field;
    }

    print join '|', @fields;
    print "\n";
}
```